# input in search box of a website  programmatically using JAVA

Tags: java, html, htmlunit

I'm making a Java program where I programmatically insert data into search field of a website and submit it programmatically using java .

After submission a new webpage is opened..

Eg if website name is `www.pqr.net/index.php`

after I make search submission I'm redirected to that page.
eg. `www.pqr.net/ind2.php`

i know i can read data using `URLCONNECTION`.

how to get the url of page where I'm redirected because I want to read the contents of that page , unless I don't know the url of the page where I'm redirected , I can't read the contents

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();


    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("www.pqr.net");


   HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("f1");

   final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByName("submitbutton");
   final HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("searc");


   textField.setValueAttribute("value");


   final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
```

Comment: Have you tried something? If so, post the code. If not, go read up on Java networking libraries.

Comment: i need to get the url of current page

Answer (score 0):

The URL of the page you are redirected to is in a [Location](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30) header of the response message.  Please refer to the specification for the details, and to the `HttpURLConnection` javadoc for the method you should use to get a Header from the response.

Comment: i need to get the url of the current htmlpage

Comment: @SahilManchanda - I answered that question.